# How to configure build.gradle to use Google Play App Signing upload certificate

Tags: android, gradle, android-signing

For .apk signing with keystore files I had something like that in my `build.gradle` file:

```
signingConfigs {
     release {
        storeFile file("../keystore.jks")
        storePassword "****"
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword "****"
     }
}
```

How do I need to setup `build.gradle` to sign the .apk with an upload certificate ?

And also, can I use same upload certificate to sign multiple apps on same Google Play account?

Comment: @Vampire I need to "Vote" and only after that "Accept" the answer, or there is another issue? :)

Comment: The oder is not significant, but you should do both

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I you have the upload key in a certificate, import that certificate into your keystore, then use it as you are used to.

And yes, you can use the same upload certificate for multiple apps. The upload certificate identifies you, not your app. It's the same as before with signing with the real certificate. You were able to sign multiple apps with the same key and doing that showing that they come from the same developer.

Comment: can you be more detailed please? I am going through the same problem and my understanding is that with google app sign-in, I can remove storepasswords and aliaspassowrd from gradle. is that correct?